# My cardviews won't always dismiss when swiped to left or right?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am using a `FrameLayout` to carry out the swipe gesture of each of my cardviews, but the cards do not always dismiss. And sometimes they just hang on the left or the right until the user swipes the card a second time.

How can I fix this?

**MyFrameLayout:**

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private static int mWidth = 200;
    MyFrameLayout touchFrameLayout;

    // Constructors 
    // i call "initialize(context)" in all of them

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        touchFrameLayout = this;

    }

    private float mDisplacementX; 
    private float mDisplacementY;
    private float mInitialTx;
    private boolean mTracking;
    private OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mWidth = (int) touchFrameLayout.getLayoutParams().width;
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    mDisplacementX = event.getRawX();
                    mDisplacementY = event.getRawY();

                    mInitialTx = getTranslationX();

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // get the delta distance in X and Y direction
                    float deltaX = event.getRawX() - mDisplacementX;
                    float deltaY = event.getRawY() - mDisplacementY;
                    // updatePressedState(false);

                    // set the touch and cancel event
                    if ((Math.abs(deltaX) > ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                            .getScaledTouchSlop() * 2 && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math
                            .abs(deltaX) / 2)
                            || mTracking) {

                        mTracking = true;

                        if (getTranslationX() <= mWidth / 2
                                && getTranslationX() >= -(mWidth / 2)) {

                            setTranslationX(mInitialTx + deltaX);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    if (mTracking) {
                        mTracking = false;
                        float currentTranslateX = getTranslationX();

                        if (currentTranslateX > (mWidth/10)) {
                            rightSwipe();
                        } else if (currentTranslateX < -(mWidth*10)) {
                            leftSwipe();
                        }

                        // comment this line if you don't want your frame layout to
                        // take its original position after releasing the touch
                        setTranslationX(0);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // handle click event
                        setTranslationX(0);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void rightSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Swipe to the right",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     DeleteCard();
    }

    private void leftSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Swipe to the left",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DeleteCard();
    }
}
```

**Xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.testing.android.layout.MyFrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/taskViewContainer"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           app:cardElevation="8dp"
           app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
           card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"> 
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </com.example.testing.android.layout.MyFrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have a list or only a single CardView as your xml shows ?

Answer (score 0):

I adapted romannurik's Android-SwipeToDismiss to do exactly that.

The code is on github with a woking sample application, and consists of:

A subclass of RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener that listens to touch events and detects when an item is being swiped, animating it accordingly.
A SwipeListener that is called in order to know if an item can be dismissed and called again when items are dismissed.
To use it, copy the class SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener to your project and use it like this

```
mAdapter = new CardViewAdapter(mItems);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
            new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(mRecyclerView,
                    new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                mItems.remove(position);
                                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                mItems.remove(position);
                                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
}
```

This can also be useful : http://www.getgoodcode.com/2013/06/swipe-to-dismiss-google-style/

Hope it works for you !